# How do I fix a leaky hydrant?

Tags: plumbing, leak, yard-hydrant

Having a problem with the release valve leaking like crazy when the hydrant is turned on. A plumber replaced the release valve a couple times and still have this issue. What can you recommend?

[image: Hydrant]

[image: Leaky release valve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the manual for this hydrant:

[Woodford Sanitary Hydrant](https://www.woodfordmfg.com/woodford/Yard_Hydrant_Pages/Model-S3.html)

Perhaps you're not pulling down on the diverter enough to close it.  If that's not it, then the diverter is either damaged or has foreign material in it that is causing it not to seal.  Either clean it out or replace it.